# How can I replace all URLs in a string with `hostnametld`?

Tags: python, regex

For example:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` `=>` `stackoverflowcom`

The following works, but not with a corner case where `https` is outside a url.

```
import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def convert_urls_to_hostnames(s):
    try:
        new_s = re.sub("http\S+", lambda match: urlparse(match.group()).hostname.replace('.','') if match.group() else urlparse(match.group()).hostname, s)
        return new_s
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return s
```

This works, mostly.

```
s = "Ask questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
print(convert_urls_to_hostnames(s))
```

Correctly Returns: `Ask questions here: stackoverflowcom`

However, it fails if `http*s` is found anywhere in the string outside a url like so:

```
s = "Urls may start with http or https like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask and https://example.com/questions/"
print(convert_urls_to_hostnames(s))
```

This returns: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'`.

Expected return: `Urls may start with http or https like so: stackoverflowcom and examplecom`

Comment: Look for `http://` in the regex, i.e. `re.sub("http://\S+", lambda ...`

Comment: Right, but that would skip urls starting with `https://`

Comment: Make the `s` optional: `http[s]?://`

Comment: Mission accomplished @JohnGordon! Thanks for making quick work of this one. Add this as an answer so I can give you your upvotes.

Comment: `"http\S+"` is not a good regex for URLs in arbitrary strings. It's nice for a proof-of-concept, but consider taking a better regex for the final code.

Comment: @JohnGordon No need to put the `s` in a character class. `https?://` is good. Be aware that URLs may legally start with `//`. This is called "protocol-relative URL". Bottom line, use a better URL regex. There are many well-tested ones to choose from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for `http://` or `https://` in the regex, i.e. `re.sub("https?://\S+", lambda ...`

Comment: I guess you placed the `[s]?` in the character class for clarity? Since it could just be `s?`.

Comment: @JohanWentholt Actually I was thinking -- incorrectly! -- that `https?` would make the whole word `https` optional instead of just the `s`.  I'll edit the answer.